# Downscale image for MNIST

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap, mnist

I'm trying to solve MNIST classification problem on Android devices. I have a trained model already, now I want to be able to recognize a single digit on the photo.

After taking a photo I make some pre-processing, before passing image to the model.
Here's an example of original image:
[image]

After that I make it black-and-white only, so it starts looking like this:
[image]

Please, don't pay attention to the changes in dimensions - the were introduced by the way I make screenshots, in the app both images still have the same size.

After casting it to BW colors I extract the number's blob, downscale it to 20*20 (respecting the aspect ratio) and then add padding aroung to make it fit the MNIST 28*28 size. The final result is the following:

[image]

Notice, that I upscaled image to show up the problem. And the problem is the following: after downscaling a lot of useful information gets lost. Sometimes the whole edges of the number are gone. Is there any way to avoid it? Maybe I can somehow make white lines thicker before downscaling?

P.S. I use Catalano framework for images processing.

**EDIT** After applying the suggested filter from the answer here's what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the framework you've mentioned,
but one thing that can be of help here, is to use some morphological operations on the original image, before going for MNIST style normalization. 
Namely, one can do an **erosion** as follows (I'm recording the approach in python, there should be analogues in the framework you use, as the operations are pretty standard).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

xx = cv2.imread('6.jpg') # your original image of 6
kernel = np.ones((20,20), np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(xx, kernel, iterations = 2)

cv2.imwrite('6A.jpg',erosion) # this will be used as a replacement for the original image
```

this will produce something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp8FL.jpg). Then, if you do the binarization of the new image (say threshold by gray intensity 150), and do the resize followed by padding, you should get something like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0KQp.png), which is more robust.

Note also, that you need to centralize the image at the very last stage (against its center of mass) before feeding to any classifier.

The end result, in MNIST's standards is  as follows [image] ( physical dimensions 28x28).

Comment: I'll try it out. Yes, Erosion filter exists in the framework I use. I was thinking in the similar way i.e. tried to blur the image for example. But I don't know a lot of image processing operations and I also did it after casting to the BW image (which made blur senseless in my case).

Comment: Am I right that in your example https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0KQp.png is still have the original size?

Comment: the 1st image in my example (after erosion) has the same size as yours. The 2nd one is 28x28 and normalized according to MNIST standard (fits into 20x20 box, and is centered by it's center of mass in 28x28). It has physical size larger in the post, as I copied it from my python notebook instead of writing the actual file on the disk.  I will put the original file's link in the answer now.

Comment: The entire workflow which should suffice here might go like this: 1. read the image in gray scale (no filters applied), 2. apply the erosion as above, 3. make binarization of the result by making all pixels above gray intensity 150 as white ( = 255 ), and everything below 150 as black ( = 0 ). 4. And then just do the normalization for MNIST on the binary image of step 3; this is how I got the last 6 in the answer.

Comment: I found out that erosion does the opposite at least on complete BW images. I.e. makes it thicker. But, there's a Dilatation filter, which does exactly what you've demonstrated for BW images. At the moment my pipeline is the following: read image in grayscale; apply adaptive threshold (Bradley); apply delatation with radius 2; extract, add padding, resize, etc. I don't center it properly yet, but that's another question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'r very welcome! Just a quick note, yes, dilation and erosion are indeed opposite operations. But it actually depends on the background color of the image, whether you'll get thickening or  shrinking of the edges. In the original example you had, it was erosion, which made it thicker!  So, one needs to take into account the background color as well (just working your way from a concrete example will do just fine), and indeed you might need to do dilation on the BW images.

Comment: Correct. I just mentioned dilation for anyone else, who might later come up with similar question.